# Keyboard shortcut to access contact Quick Search?

Tags: dashboard, ui

Is there a way to activate the contact Quick Search form field at the top of each page, with a keyboard shortcut rather than moving the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shortcut and others can be found by clicking on the "Access Keys" help icon at the bottom of many CiviCRM pages.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The form field is assigned "q" as its HTML accesskey. I don't know about other browsers, but you can activate it in Firefox by pressing alt+shift+q (Windows/Linux), or on Mac: either control+option+q or control+alt+q.